# Understand if two different pdf are the same research paper

Tags: java, pdf, hash

I'm thinking to write a simple research paper manager. 
The idea is to have a repository containing for each paper its metadata

```
paper_id -> [title, authors, journal, comments...]
```

Since it would be nice to have the possibility to import the paper dump of a friend,
I'm thinking on how to generate the paper_id of a paper: IMHO should be produced
by the text of the pdf, to garantee that two different collections have the same ids only for the same papers. 
At the moment, I extract the text of the first page using the iText library (removing the possible annotations), and i compute a simhash footprint from the text. 
the main problem is that sometime text is slightly different (yes, it happens! for example [this](http://www.chato.cl/papers/boldi_2008_query_flow_graph.pdf) and [this](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/QueryFlowGraph.pdf)) so i would like to be tolerant.
With simhash i can compute how much the are similar the original document, so in case the footprint is not in the repo, i'll have to iterate over the collection looking for 
'near' footprints.

I'm not convinced by this method, could you suggest some better way to produce a signature
(short, numerical or alphanumerical) for those kind of documents?

**UPDATE** I had this idea: divide the first page in 8 (more or less) not-overlapping squares, covering all the page, then consider the text in each square
and generate a simhash signature. At the end I'll have a 8x64=512bit signature and I can consider
two papers the same if the sum of the differences between their simhash signatures sets is under a certain treshold.

Comment: Well, to compare two documents you could probably use signal processing concepts, similar to doing a Fourier transform on the text.  But for your purposes probably some scheme where you identify and extract keywords and order them somehow might work pretty well.  Of course, one problem is that the same basic paper may be reworked 3-4 times for different journals -- are they the same or different?

Comment: yes, that's another problem.. they should be different, but people should add additional content in each paper so should not happen, this tool would be useful also for reviewing ;)

Comment: The other thing, obviously, is to extract the authors' names and use that as a first qualification (assuming you're not intent on discovering plagiarism).

Comment: it is complicated, since extract authors from the pdf is hard, and so I should query google or other external services withe the title.. and often author names are written in different way so mmmm

Comment: Another thing you should do is check the bottom margin for publishing info, such as "CIKM’08, October 26–30, 2008, Napa Valley, California, USA. Copyright 2008 ACM 978-1-59593-991-3/08/10 ...$5.00."  It won't usually help you identify dupes, but you can use it for other cross-referencing purposes.

Comment: (And, of course, if you Google the above reference you also find [this article](http://ciir-publications.cs.umass.edu/getpdf.php?id=841) from the same conference, which may be of use in your work.)

Comment: Problem with this approach is that many authors use to put online their papers without the conference/journal footer (e.g., [this](http://www.chato.cl/papers/boldi_2008_query_flow_graph.pdf)). I think i should use something like  the frequency distribution of words..

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking the bottom margin info would help identify dupes so much as just help you with cataloging.  (But as your reference demonstrates, the primary author's name is often in the link name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you actually have a function that inputs two texts and returns a measure of their similarity, you do not have to iterate the entire Repository. 
Given an article that is not in the repository, you can iterate only articles that have approximately the same *length*. for example, given an article that have 1000 characters, you will compare it to articles having between 950 and 1050 characters. For this you will need to have a data structure that maps ranges to articles and you will have to fine tune the size of the range. Range too large- too many items in each range. Range too small- higher potential of a miss.

Of course this will fail on some edge cases. For example, if you have two documents that the second is simply the first that was copy pasted twice: you would probably want them to be considered equal, but you will not even compare them since they are too far apart in length. There are methods to deal with that also, but you probably 'Ain't gonna need it'.

Comment: mmm it does not convince me, as you observed, i'll have to accept all paper with a length falling in a range of characters. Problem is that since a large number of articles are bounded to 10 or 15 pages,I'm worried that a large number of articles will fall in the same range.

Comment: It is a valid concern. However, I suggest that instead of guessing- just see for yourself! Create a histogram of the paper lengths, you might be surprised. The fact that they are limited to 15 pages actually says nothing.

Comment: I agree, I'll try but the solution I proposed (see the update) seems more robust, to me, (maybe minhash is better than simhash). Anyway i cound use the length as an extrafeature, you are right, thanks.

Comment: But the problem (as I understood it from your description) is not with establishing the similarity- this is handled perfectly by the SimHash itself. You problem is that in order to find near duplicates, you need to perform the comparison for each document in your corpus. What I am suggesting, is reducing the size of the search space. What you devised is a technique to reduce the time of the similarity computation itself. They can be combined of course.

Comment: Also you are assuming that two articles are the same if their first page is the same (or nearly the same). This is not necessarily true if the article was released in more than one addition (e.g. article was released not in it complete form or without certain appendices).